# Experiment runtime on IBMQ

Tags: programming, ibm-q-experience, ibm-quantum-devices

I have been trying to get the runtime of my experiment on IBM's quantum computer. I am using the classic stuff, i.e

```
job = execute(qwalk_circuit, backend='ibmq_16_melbourne', shots=1000)
results = job.result()
results.get_counts()
print(results.data())
```

I saw on another post that you could see the runtime by using `results.get_data()`, but that doesnt work anymore, giving me an error that the `get_data()` attribute does not exist. Is there another way to pull the runtime of my experiment from IBM's quantum computer backend?

My imports, in case I am missing something there:

```
# importing QISKit
from qiskit import Aer, IBMQ
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, ClassicalRegister, QuantumRegister, execute
from qiskit import IBMQ, BasicAer
from qiskit.providers.ibmq import least_busy
from qiskit.tools.monitor import job_monitor
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was recently looking for a similar solution. Hope this helps.

```
job = execute(qc, backend=backend, shots=1024)
results = job.result()
print(results.time_taken)
```

You can also check all the values stored in result as it is a dictionary by printing it:

```
print(results)
```

Here you can check for all the information that is available within the dictionary and you can also observe the value for *'time_taken'*

Answer (score 3):

`results.get_data()` was replaced by `results.data()`. The new function returns (almost) the same information, but the runtime attribute was removed. As far as I know, there is no official way to get the runtime of your job on the computer.

There are some ways to get it through your own code, but keep in mind these are not official methods of doing so, and the times might not be very accurate. One way would be to call `time.time()` right when you send your job, and compare it to a `time.time()` call right when your job completes. However, this would include any time the job spent waiting in queue. You could also try calling the first `time.time()` call when the `job.status()` is in a running state, and then call another `time.time()` once the job completes. This should, in theory, bypass any time the job spends in queue.

However, the feature may be brought back in the future, so I would keep an eye on future release notes as well.

Comment: Hm, I tried calculating the time before sending the job and it did include the queue time. Didn' think of doing it before the status command though, I will give it a go! Thanks very much :) I wonder why it was removed, I would think that it is quite important info to have...

Comment: No problem. I also have used the first method before for my own personal knowledge of the runtime. I also have not yet tried the other method of only calling `time.time()` once the `job.status()` returns RUNNING, but I do not see why that would not work. Good luck though!